# How do I make a pickaxe that can break bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm fine if you just give me the NBT or something but I'm on an anarchy realm and need to give my friend a pick to break bedrock since he's on console and can't download exploits.

Comment: [Identical question for Java Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/373175/185203)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make a wooden pickaxe break bedrock with commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/373175/is-it-possible-to-make-a-wooden-pickaxe-break-bedrock-with-commands)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the special `can_place_on` and `can_destroy` tags for MCBE.

```
/give @s minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["bedrock"]}}
```

but there's still a problem, because bedrock *can't* be broken, because that's the whole point, it's a barrier to stop you falling into the void! So even with a `can_destroy` tag for `bedrock`, you can swing your pickaxe at it as much as you want, but that bedrock isn't going to break.

You could retexture a different block to look like bedrock, but that's an entirely different mechanic for an entirely different post. Check out some info on [add-ons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Add-on) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a command to a) make bedrock breakable, since bedrock cannot be broken (requires significant command knowledge), and b) to give yourself a pick which can break bedrock (significantly less command knowledge required). However, this would most likely allow players to dig out of the world (bad thing). Xboxes are not good for modding, as the only NBT tags are the `can_place` and `can_destroy` tags.
If you're in Adventure mode, and you managed to make bedrock breakable, use the following command:

```
/give @s minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["bedrock"]}}
```

Comment: In that case, you would use a command, since bedrock *cannot* be broken. However this would require the player to have significant command knowledge and would most likely allow players to dig out of the world. Xboxes are not good for modding, as the only NBT tags are the `can_place` and `can_destroy` tags.