# Is it possible to make a wooden pickaxe break bedrock with commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i'm trying to do different kinds of pickaxes and axes, and I don't now a way to change the blocks that a pickaxe can break. Like how do i to make a diamond pickaxe break bedrock.
if possible teach how to do it on 1.16.1.
I found that command...
`/give @s minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["bedrock"]}}`
...But it isn't for 1.16.1

Comment: I don’t think you can.

Comment: [Identical question for Bedrock Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/371313/185203) (despite the confusing name, "Bedrock Edition" has nothing to do with the Bedrock block)

Comment: You cannot break bedrock in survival or adventure mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the command you found is a Bedrock edition command.

You can use the `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` tags for MCJE.

```
/give @s minecraft:wooden_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:bedrock"]}
```

but there's still a problem, because bedrock *can't* be broken, because that's the whole point, it's a barrier to stop you falling into the void! So even with a `CanDestroy` tag for `bedrock`, you can swing your pickaxe at it as much as you want, but that bedrock isn't going to break.

You could retexture a different block to look like bedrock, but that's an entirely different mechanic for an entirely different post.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this. However, you can use NBT and passive bedrock-breaking commands in command blocks.

First, have a command block set to repeat, with command:

```
/execute @a nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:wooden_pickaxe",tag:{display:{Name:"Bedrock Breaker"}}}}
```

This will check if a player is holding a wooden pickaxe with name "Bedrock Breaker". The name is there to make sure that players won't fall into the void on accident because they were holding a wooden pickaxe on bedrock.

Next, have a chain command block with command, set to Conditional:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ bedrock 0 tag @s add bedrock
```

This checks if the person with "Bedrock Breaker" is standing on bedrock.

Next, to break it, have another chain command block, set to Conditional:

```
/execute @a[tag=bedrock]@a ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ air
```

This destroys the bedrock block under a player holding the "Bedrock Breaker" pickaxe.

This is optional: This command gives the person(s) with "Bedrock Breaker" pickaxe a bedrock block as an item drop.

```
/execute @a[tag=bedrock] ~ ~ ~ give @s bedrock 1
```

This removes the tag `bedrock` so the player cannot switch to different items and still break bedrock.

```
/tag @a[tag=bedrock] remove bedrock
```

The conditionals are there to make sure that the player MUST be holding a Bedrock Breaker pickaxe. Otherwise, the player could run around, breaking all the bedrock that they are standing on, eventually falling into the void. I hope this helps.